# Does sbaz work with Scala 2.9.1.final?

Tags: scala, sbaz

Under Windows with version 2.9.0.1 simply typing 'sbaz' at the command prompt works. Under 2.9.1.final doing the same thing I get '\scala was unexpected at this time'

Comment: It looks like sbaz is [gone](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-language/QK4rTszzIeM/Mu4N_1zu_K8J) in 2.9.1-1

Answer (score 0):

It should work, considering the [sbaz-gui works with sbaz and 2.9.1](http://code.google.com/p/another-sbaz-gui/wiki/UpgradingFromRcToFinal) (and that sbaz is mentioned in the [Scala distribution page for 2.9.1](http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads))